# How to convert the pseudo-version from Golang modules to a git commit?

Tags: git, go, go-modules

I have two git repositories containing go modules, let's call them `controller` and `api`. `controller` imports `api`, so the `go.mod` file in the `controller` repo has a dependency to the module contained in the `api` repo.

My problem is that for the code in `controller` to run, I not only need the go code from `api`, but also some static files (which are generated from the code) contained in the repo. As far as I know, there is no way of packaging these static files into the go module so that they are automatically imported into my `vendor` folder.

My current approach is trying to add the folder with the static files as a sparsely checked out git submodule. However, in order to keep this submodule in sync with the imported go source code from `api`, I'd like to have a small shell script that automatically checks out the commit referenced by the version of the `api` module in the `go.mod` file.

While this probably works for release versions, I also want this to work for unreleased versions which have a pseudo-version of the format `<semantic version>-<commit timestamp>-<commit hash prefix>` in the `go.mod` file.

Is there any way to compute the *full* commit hash out of this pseudo-version? I am assuming that this is somehow possible, because `go mod vendor` is able to checkout the correct version, but the only process that comes to my mind is searching for commits that happened at the given time across all branches and then choosing the one where the hash prefix matches ... and that sounds really hard to do in bash.

Any ideas how to solve this? Alternative ways of importing my static files from `api` into `controller` in a way that keeps them in sync with the vendored version of the `api` module are also appreciated.

Comment: "As far as I know, there is no way of packaging these static files into the go module" Did you consider using package embed to actually embed them?

Comment: A [git hash prefix is sufficient to identify a commit within a repository](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection), but as the last comment mentioned, you probably want to bundle the artifacts in some other way

Comment: I only had a quick look at the embed stuff, but as I understood it, this is only for embedding static files into compiled binaries and not useful for adding them to the imported package. But maybe I'm wrong here, will check again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Volker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1266756/volker) for the correct answer. It is actually quite easy to do using the `embed` package and works well.

A drawback of this solution is that only files within a go package can be embedded. Since my generated files were in a top-level folder that did not contain any go code, I had to wrap them in a dummy package to embed them.